# How to create more than one XLSX sheet from HTML table in js-xlsx (sheetjs)?

Tags: javascript, sheetjs, js-xlsx

I am using [sheetjs](https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.17.0/dist/xlsx.full.min.js) to convert some of my table data into xlsx format (and download later).

However, how can I add more than one sheet into the xlsx?

The current code is:

```
var elt = document.getElementById('table_instance');
var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {sheet:"Sheet 1"});
```

What I'm looking for is:

```
var elt = document.getElementById('table_instance');
var elt2 = document.getElementById('table_instance2');
var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(
    [elt, {sheet:"Sheet 1"}
    [elt2, {sheet:"Sheet 2"}
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step: 1**
Create two separate sheets

```
var elt = document.getElementById('table_instance');
var elt2 = document.getElementById('table_instance2');

var ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(elt);
var ws2 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(elt2);
```

**Step: 2** Create an empty workbook

```
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
```

**Step: 3** Append the sheets to the workbook

```
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet 1");
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws2, "Sheet 2");
```

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/pm6o8vwj/15/)**

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`table_to_sheet`](https://docs.sheetjs.com/#html-table-input) utility function that returns a sheet object that you can insert into a workbook.

The example below shows this with a brand new workbook, with two sheets from two different tables:

```js
// html
const tbl1 = document.getElementById("test1");
const tbl2 = document.getElementById("test2");

// new workbook - could be some existing book as well
let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

// table_to_sheet for different sheets from html table
let ws1 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(tbl1);
let ws2 = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(tbl2);
// ... etc

// add sheets to workbook
// sheet names are your choice
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws1, "Sheet1");
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws2, "Sheet2");

// test persisted in sheet objects
const test1 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets["Sheet1"], {header: 1});
const test2 = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets["Sheet2"], {header: 1});
console.log(`Sheet1: ${JSON.stringify(test1)}`);
console.log(`Sheet2: ${JSON.stringify(test2)}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.0/xlsx.min.js"></script>
<table id="test1">
<tr><td>a1</td><td>b1</td><td>c1</td></tr>
<tr><td>d1</td><td>e1</td><td>f1</td></tr>
<tr><td>g1</td><td>h1</td><td>i1</td></tr>
</table>

<table id="test2">
<tr><td>a2</td><td>b2</td><td>c2</td></tr>
<tr><td>d2</td><td>e2</td><td>f2</td></tr>
<tr><td>g2</td><td>h2</td><td>i2</td></tr>
</table>
```